# How to get indexOf a property in an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties

I have an JavaScript object with following structure.

```
    var emp = {
      id : 1,
      name : "john",
      salary: 1000 
  }
```

Is there is a way in JavaScript to find out the indexOf a propetry?

so `indexOfProperty(emp, "name")` should give me 1.

Comment: Props inside objects are not ordered in javascript.

Comment: what do you want with this information? object's keys are not ordered with `Object.keys`.

Comment: why would order matter? @NinaScholz

Comment: The problem with getting the index of a property is that it may not always be the same index depending on any other properties that have been added to the object. You may get different results depending on different browsers or libraries you have included in your project.

Comment: I sense an X Y problem.... @Amitabh, can you please explain the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking about your attempted solution?

Comment: @pbrianq, the index reflects the order.

Comment: @NinaScholz I get it now. thanks

Answer (score -1):

`Object.keys(emp).indexOf("name")`

This only is useful if it's a check if the index exists, since as other comments have stated the order is not guaranteed by `Object.keys()` or in JS objects in general

[Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will guarantee insertion-ordered ordering

Answer (score -1):

```js
   var emp = {
      id : 1,
      name : "john",
      salary: 1000 
  }
  
  var property = Object.keys(emp).indexOf('name');
  
  console.log(property);
```